# Pandas merge based on substring match

Tags: python, pandas

df1 and df2 both have similar number of rows nearly 35k

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Hostname': ['usa-101', 'usa-201']})
```

```
      Hostname
    0  usa-101
    1  usa-201
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Hostname':['asdad-usa-101-xyz.com', 'AAAAA-usa-201-XZCZC.AAAAA.AAAAAA'], 'Value':['15.5', '16.6'], 'Another value':['111', '222']})
```

```
    Out[8]:
                               Hostname Value Another Value
    0             asdad-usa-101-xyz.com  15.5           111
    1  AAAAA-usa-201-XZCZC.AAAAA.AAAAAA  16.6           222
```

My requirement:-
I want to lookup df1.Hostname in df2.Hostname and if df1.Hostname is contained inside df2.Hostname, i want to merge df1 with df2 to give result like

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Hostname': ['usa-101', 'usa-201'], 'Value':['15.5', '16.6'], 'Another value':['111', '222']}
```

```
      Hostname Value Another Value
    0  usa-101  15.5           111
    1  usa-201  16.6           222
```

I understand i can do a merge if i can cleanup data in df2 so that hostname columns of both dfs match but that is really difficult because there is no pattern that i can use to split and extract. the hostname value in df2 are extremely random but it can contain df1.hostname anywhere in the entire string.

Thanks...

Comment: use regex to extract usa-101 to a column. Then match on that column with df1.

Comment: did you try `df2['new'] = df2['Hostname'].str.extract(r'(usa\-\d+)')`

Comment: I can't use a regex match because the hostname column in df1 / df2 can contain 34k rows of data. moreover the values can be extremely random.... its not just usa.... it could be any string value.... but that string value needs to be chceked if it is inside any row in df2.hostname columns

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to match hostname in df2 with hostname in df1 using iteration:

```
def match(longtext):
    for x in df1.Hostname.tolist():
        if x in longtext:
            return x
    return None

df2.Hostname = df2.Hostname.apply(lambda x: match(x))
df2
```

the result look like this

[image]

Comment: With this approach... i can use this df2 after apply() to merge back with df1. Now since the Hostname fields match. Contrary to the extract regex methods... where its difficult to predict the regex because the string in df1 could be anything and any pattern..

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

1.Combine the dataframes to create all possible matches:

```
df1['temp'] = 1 #temporary keys to create all combinations
df2['temp'] = 1 #The temp key will be removed next line
df_combined = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='temp').drop('temp',axis=1)

df_combined:

Hostname_x  Hostname_y                         Value    Another value
0   usa-101 asdad-usa-101-xyz.com               15.5    111
1   usa-101 AAAAA-usa-201-XZCZC.AAAAA.AAAAAA    16.6    222
2   usa-201 asdad-usa-101-xyz.com               15.5    111
3   usa-201 AAAAA-usa-201-XZCZC.AAAAA.AAAAAA    16.6    222
```

2. Do the comparison :

```
result_df = df_combined.apply(lambda row : row if row.Hostname_x in row.Hostname_y 
                           else np.nan ,axis=1)
result_df.dropna().drop('Hostname_y',axis=1)

result_df:

Hostname_x  Value   Another value
0   usa-101 15.5    111
3   usa-201 16.6    222
```

Comment: You need to explain how you got usa-101 mapped to 15.5. This is not how you do it. It has to match on the substring within df1 and df2.

Comment: I check either way now.

Comment: @Inputvector Why are you comparison other direction ? or row.Hostname_y in row.Hostname_x

If i only use df_combined.apply(lambda row : row if row.Hostname_x in row.Hostname_y else np.nan, axis=1 i get the exact same result

Comment: Also i get this error using this approach...

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.8 GiB for an array with shape (1449975135,) and data type int64

34k rows in each dataframe so that merge on temp=1 will probably create millions of rows

Comment: I don't know if there is any other way to solve this without create all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to merge the two dataframes. It looks like you want to extract the `usa-nnn` value from the hostname and make it available as a new column.

To do this, you can give:

```
df2['new_Hostname'] = df2['Hostname'].str.extract(r'(usa\-\d+)')
```

This will give you:

```
                           Hostname Value Another value new_Hostname
0             asdad-usa-101-xyz.com  15.5           111      usa-101
1  AAAAA-usa-201-XZCZC.AAAAA.AAAAAA  16.6           222      usa-201
```

If your df1 has many columns and you want to merge df1 with df2, you can always do a df.merge as follows:

```
df_new = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=  ['Hostname'],
                   right_on= ['new_Hostname'], 
                   how = 'left')
```

This will give you:

```
  Hostname_x                        Hostname_y Value Another value new_Hostname
0    usa-101             asdad-usa-101-xyz.com  15.5           111      usa-101
1    usa-201  AAAAA-usa-201-XZCZC.AAAAA.AAAAAA  16.6           222      usa-201
```

You can always decide to remove the columns you don't need with the drop statement. You need to add `.drop('col_name',axis=1)` where col_name is the column you want to drop.

If you need the command it is `.drop(['Hostname_x','Hostname_y'],axis=1)`